# Need help on simple pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Newbie to SQL and doing some exercises having trouble with a simple pivot

I have a table,

```
Labnumber : Silicon : Aluminum : Magnesium
9086-1    :  7.05   :    15    :    .7
```

What I need is :

```
labnumber   9086-1 
Silicon      7.05 
Aluminum     .15 
Magnesium    .7
```

I have played around with the pivot command

```
SELECT LabNumber,ElementFROM XRF UNPIVOT ( labnumber1 for Element in(Silicon,Aluminum,Calcium,Magnesium) )As test
```

But all i get is this

```
LabNumber Element 
9086-1    Silicon 
9086-1    Aluminum 
9086-1    Calcium 
9086-1    Magnesium
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation here

```
SELECT 
    Labnumber = MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'Labnumber' THEN column END)
    Silicon   = MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'Silicon' THEN column  END)
    Aluminum  = MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'Aluminum' THEN column END)
    Magnesium = MAX(CASE WHEN column = 'Magnesium' THEN column END)
FROM
    table
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `apply` for this purpose:

```
select which, val
from xrf cross apply
     (values ('Labnumber', Labnumber),
             ('Silicon', Silicon),
             ('Aluminum', Aluminum),
             ('Magnesium', Magnesium)
     ) v(which, val);
```